# Unable to send SOAP request from ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects, soapui, soap-client

i am trying to post a SOAP request from my reactjs Application. When i try to send the same request from Postman i am able to get the response but not from reactjs Application

below is my SOAP Request

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>******</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">*****</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <taxCalculationRequest xmlns="http://www.sabrix.com/services/taxcalculationservice/2011-09-01">
            <INDATA version="G">
                <INVOICE>
                    <CALLING_SYSTEM_NUMBER>DEV</CALLING_SYSTEM_NUMBER>
                    <HOST_SYSTEM>HMS</HOST_SYSTEM>
                    <COMPANY_NAME>ALJ Hospital and Rehabiliation</COMPANY_NAME>
                    <EXTERNAL_COMPANY_ID>ALJ-HMS-01</EXTERNAL_COMPANY_ID>
                    <COMPANY_ROLE>S</COMPANY_ROLE>
                    <CUSTOMER_NAME>KHAYRIAH MOHAMMED AHMED HARIRI</CUSTOMER_NAME>
                    <CUSTOMER_NUMBER>17154</CUSTOMER_NUMBER>
                    <INVOICE_NUMBER>0</INVOICE_NUMBER>
                    <INVOICE_DATE>2022-03-01</INVOICE_DATE>
                    <CURRENCY_CODE>SAR</CURRENCY_CODE>
                    <IS_AUDITED>False</IS_AUDITED>
                    <IS_CREDIT>False</IS_CREDIT>
                    <CALCULATION_DIRECTION>F</CALCULATION_DIRECTION>
                    <POINT_OF_TITLE_TRANSFER>I</POINT_OF_TITLE_TRANSFER>
                    <USER_ELEMENT>
                        <NAME>ATTRIBUTE1</NAME>
                        <VALUE>1017106855</VALUE>
                    </USER_ELEMENT>
                    <LINE ID="1">
                        <COMMODITY_CODE>RC01</COMMODITY_CODE>
                        <PRODUCT_CODE>RC01</PRODUCT_CODE>
                        <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
                        <DESCRIPTION>CONSULTANT PHYSICIAN ASSESMENT</DESCRIPTION>
                        <GROSS_AMOUNT>50</GROSS_AMOUNT>
                        <QUANTITIES>
                            <QUANTITY>
                                <AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
                            </QUANTITY>
                        </QUANTITIES>
                        <SHIP_FROM>
                            <COUNTRY>SA</COUNTRY>
                        </SHIP_FROM>
                        <SHIP_TO>
                            <COUNTRY>SA</COUNTRY>
                        </SHIP_TO>
                        <TRANSACTION_TYPE>DS</TRANSACTION_TYPE>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE1</NAME>
                            <VALUE>False</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE2</NAME>
                            <VALUE>15.0000</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE3</NAME>
                            <VALUE>5</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE10</NAME>
                            <VALUE>71270101100100</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE11</NAME>
                            <VALUE>34049999932000</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE ID="2">
                        <COMMODITY_CODE>RC01</COMMODITY_CODE>
                        <PRODUCT_CODE>RC01</PRODUCT_CODE>
                        <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
                        <DESCRIPTION>CONSULTANT PHYSICIAN ASSESMENT</DESCRIPTION>
                        <GROSS_AMOUNT>50</GROSS_AMOUNT>
                        <QUANTITIES>
                            <QUANTITY>
                                <AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
                            </QUANTITY>
                        </QUANTITIES>
                        <SHIP_FROM>
                            <COUNTRY>SA</COUNTRY>
                        </SHIP_FROM>
                        <SHIP_TO>
                            <COUNTRY>SA</COUNTRY>
                        </SHIP_TO>
                        <TRANSACTION_TYPE>DS</TRANSACTION_TYPE>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE1</NAME>
                            <VALUE>False</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE2</NAME>
                            <VALUE>False</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE4</NAME>
                            <VALUE>50.0000</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE10</NAME>
                            <VALUE>False</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE11</NAME>
                            <VALUE>False</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                    </LINE>
                </INVOICE>
            </INDATA>
        </taxCalculationRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

below is my javascript code

```
const url="***"
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


  const handleClick=async()=>{
    xhr.open("POST", url)
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    xhr.send(xmltemplate)
   
  }
const xmltemplate=`
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>******</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">*****</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <taxCalculationRequest xmlns="http://www.sabrix.com/services/taxcalculationservice/2011-09-01">
            <INDATA version="G">
                <INVOICE>
                    <CALLING_SYSTEM_NUMBER>DEV</CALLING_SYSTEM_NUMBER>
                    <HOST_SYSTEM>HMS</HOST_SYSTEM>
                    <COMPANY_NAME>ALJ Hospital and Rehabiliation</COMPANY_NAME>
                    <EXTERNAL_COMPANY_ID>ALJ-HMS-01</EXTERNAL_COMPANY_ID>
                    <COMPANY_ROLE>S</COMPANY_ROLE>
                    <CUSTOMER_NAME>KHAYRIAH MOHAMMED AHMED HARIRI</CUSTOMER_NAME>
                    <CUSTOMER_NUMBER>17154</CUSTOMER_NUMBER>
                    <INVOICE_NUMBER>0</INVOICE_NUMBER>
                    <INVOICE_DATE>2022-03-01</INVOICE_DATE>
                    <CURRENCY_CODE>SAR</CURRENCY_CODE>
                    <IS_AUDITED>False</IS_AUDITED>
                    <IS_CREDIT>False</IS_CREDIT>
                    <CALCULATION_DIRECTION>F</CALCULATION_DIRECTION>
                    <POINT_OF_TITLE_TRANSFER>I</POINT_OF_TITLE_TRANSFER>
                    <USER_ELEMENT>
                        <NAME>ATTRIBUTE1</NAME>
                        <VALUE>1017106855</VALUE>
                    </USER_ELEMENT>
                    <LINE ID="1">
                        <COMMODITY_CODE>RC01</COMMODITY_CODE>
                        <PRODUCT_CODE>RC01</PRODUCT_CODE>
                        <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
                        <DESCRIPTION>CONSULTANT PHYSICIAN ASSESMENT</DESCRIPTION>
                        <GROSS_AMOUNT>50</GROSS_AMOUNT>
                        <QUANTITIES>
                            <QUANTITY>
                                <AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
                            </QUANTITY>
                        </QUANTITIES>
                        <SHIP_FROM>
                            <COUNTRY>SA</COUNTRY>
                        </SHIP_FROM>
                        <SHIP_TO>
                            <COUNTRY>SA</COUNTRY>
                        </SHIP_TO>
                        <TRANSACTION_TYPE>DS</TRANSACTION_TYPE>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE1</NAME>
                            <VALUE>False</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE2</NAME>
                            <VALUE>15.0000</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE3</NAME>
                            <VALUE>5</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE10</NAME>
                            <VALUE>71270101100100</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE11</NAME>
                            <VALUE>34049999932000</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE ID="2">
                        <COMMODITY_CODE>RC01</COMMODITY_CODE>
                        <PRODUCT_CODE>RC01</PRODUCT_CODE>
                        <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
                        <DESCRIPTION>CONSULTANT PHYSICIAN ASSESMENT</DESCRIPTION>
                        <GROSS_AMOUNT>50</GROSS_AMOUNT>
                        <QUANTITIES>
                            <QUANTITY>
                                <AMOUNT>1</AMOUNT>
                            </QUANTITY>
                        </QUANTITIES>
                        <SHIP_FROM>
                            <COUNTRY>SA</COUNTRY>
                        </SHIP_FROM>
                        <SHIP_TO>
                            <COUNTRY>SA</COUNTRY>
                        </SHIP_TO>
                        <TRANSACTION_TYPE>DS</TRANSACTION_TYPE>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE1</NAME>
                            <VALUE>False</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE2</NAME>
                            <VALUE>False</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE4</NAME>
                            <VALUE>50.0000</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE10</NAME>
                            <VALUE>False</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                        <USER_ELEMENT>
                            <NAME>ATTRIBUTE11</NAME>
                            <VALUE>False</VALUE>
                        </USER_ELEMENT>
                    </LINE>
                </INVOICE>
            </INDATA>
        </taxCalculationRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
`
```

Whenever i try to post this request i am getting CORS error

Comment: The API server doesn't allow CORS, plain and simple. In order to use the API you need to route the requests through your own backend.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)